# cuLaunchKernel failed: too many resources requested for launch

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I have been trying to parallelize a code of mine using pycuda. I need to initialize 10^5 threads with each thread running around 4000 iterations. This should be well withing the block and grid limits of my GPU (grid = (98,1,1), block = (1024,1,1)). However executing the program gives me the following error: "cuLaunchKernel failed: too many resources requested for launch"

Here's the code (please don't worry about the cuda kernel functions, I have tested them separately in a .cu file and they work completely fine):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import pycuda.autoinit

mod = SourceModule("""
#include<math.h>

__device__ void iterate(double r,double *x,double *y,int n){
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        *x = r * (3 * *y + 1) * *x * (1 - *x);
        *y = r * (3 * *x + 1) * *y * (1 - *y);
    }
    
}

__global__ void calc_lyap(double* arr,double* lyap,int n){

    int blocknum = blockIdx.z * (gridDim.x * gridDim.y) + blockIdx.y * (gridDim.x) + blockIdx.x;
    int threadnum = threadIdx.z * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y) + threadIdx.y * (blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    
    int index = blocknum * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z) + threadnum;
    
    double d0 = pow(10,-12);
    
    double r = arr[index];
    
    double x1=0.1,y1=0.1;
    
    iterate(r,&x1,&y1,1000);
    
    double x2 = x1, y2 = x1 + d0;
    
    double sum=0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        iterate(r,&x1,&y1,1);
        iterate(r,&x2,&y2,1);
            
        double d1 = sqrt(pow((x1-x2),2) + pow((y1-y2),2));
        
        if(d1!=0){
            sum+=log2(d1/d0);
        }
        
        x2 = x1 + d0 * (x2 - x1) / d1;
        y2 = y1 + d0 * (y2 - y1) / d1;
    }
    
    sum = sum/n;
    
    lyap[index] = sum;  
}
                   
""")

lyap = mod.get_function("calc_lyap")

arr_d = gpuarray.to_gpu(np.linspace(0.4,1.2,10**5))
lyap_d = gpuarray.to_gpu(np.zeros(10**5))
n = gpuarray.to_gpu(np.array([3000]))

lyap(arr_d,lyap_d,n[0],grid=(10**5//1024+1,1,1),block=(1024,1,1))

lyap_ = lyap_d.get()
print(lyap_)
```

I tried reducing the size of the problem to just a sample i.e I changed 10^5 to just 10 and the block and grid dimensions to grid=(1,1,1) and block=(10,1,1) but it still yields the same error.

Python version: 3.10.8
Pycuda version: 2022.2.2
Compiler version: nvcc 11.8.89
OS: Windows
GPU: Nvidia RTX 3050 Mobile Laptop GPU

Comment: "each thread running around 4000 iterations" To me it looks like every thread is running ~n^2 iterations which is quite a lot for n>=3000. I don't quite see why this would cause the given error, as the compiler should not be able to fully unroll these loops and therefore cause the stack to be too big, but instead of decreasing the number of threads, I would decrease the number of iterations and see if it helps for a first step.

Comment: OT: 1. Don't use `pow(x, 2)` to square values, just use `x * x`. It should be faster and has the same or better quality. 2. If your problem/input data is one-dimensional, just ignore `.y` and `.z` for `gridDim`, `blockDim`, `threadIdx` and `blockIdx`. "Linearizing" them all into one big index just makes the code harder to read (and adds unnecessary integer calculations).

Comment: @paleonix I tried bringing down the number of iterations 10 and 100... neither worked. Moreover the iterations wouldn't be n^2 as the "iterate" function within the for loop has n=1 which mean the "iterate" calls within the for loop are O(1).  Also like I had mentioned this program and kernel functions work completely fine when run in a seperate .cu file, hence I don't think that the problem is in the kernel functions.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's the problem when variables of the same name have different values in different (but close) parts of the code...

Comment: For the future, provide a "minimal" example, i.e. when the kernel isn't the problem, the same error should appear with a minimal kernel (e.g. a copy kernel).

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I get some deadlocks which I can't explain (they vanish when adding print statements to the host code), but nothing about a failed kernel launch.

Comment: Maybe this is just some kind of botched installation issue. Please add details about your hardware and software environment to the question (edit it). E.g. pycuda version, python version, CUDA version, host compiler and its version, which GPU you are using, Linux or Windows...

Comment: @paleonix will add the software and hardware details to the question soon.. in the meantime could you explain to me how you tried to reproduce the error, i'm just curious about the deadlocks.

Comment: I installed `pycuda` using pip and ran your code. This is likely some issue about my environment and has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Can you execute [this demo](https://github.com/inducer/pycuda/blob/main/examples/demo.py), or do you get the same error?

Comment: @paleonix No I'm able to execute the program , it throws an error when I make the "lyap" function call though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going through the CUDA Documentation I found the docs for "CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_OUT_OF_RESOURCES = 701", which mentions that this error not only occurs when you have too many arguments but also when your arguments are of the wrong type i.e passing int64 values when you have used "int" in c which is typically 32 bytes. My mistake here lied in the initialization of the variable n I pass as an parameter.

```py
n = gpuarray.to_gpu(np.array([3000]))
```

The first mistake was that np.array automatically intializes your array to float64, moreover the error still persisted when I changed the code to:

```py
n = gpuarray.to_gpu(np.array([3000]).astype(np.int32))
```

However it finally worked when I initialized n as,

```py
n = np.int32(3000)
lyap(arr_d,lyap_d,n,grid=(10**5//1024+1,1,1),block=(1024,1,1))
```

So my mistake was that I passed a parameter of the wrong type, although I dont understand why it would work when I initialized it as an int32 array and passed the index 0 value as the parameter. I'm assuming it has something to do with how pycuda and numpy store their array elements.

Comment: Ah, yes, the kernel parameters should be in host memory. They will be transferred as part of the kernel launch. I.e. the pointer variable holding the address to a `gpuarray` also lies in host memory. Weird that I couldn't reproduce it.